# Can't switch text handler in telegram bot api python

Tags: python, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I have created 2 command handlers, they react on commands: /search and /myvkplaylist. Inside of them, I have created text handlers for getting an answer. But this text handler can't switch in this situation: User chooses /search command, enter the answer, text handler gets the right answer, but after that, if the user chooses /my playlist command, bot still gives a result from first text handler of /search command. I can't find the mistake, but I am sure it's something stupid.

```
import telebot
import const

#Подключаюсь к боту
bot = telebot.TeleBot(const.token)


#Поиск по запросу
#Парсим команду серч
@bot.message_handler(commands=["search", "start"])
def handle_command(message):
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, parse_mode='HTML',
                     text="<b>What are you looking for?</b> \nFor example: <i>Elton John</i> or <i>Smells like teen spirit</i>")

    @bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
    def handle_text(message2):
        # Получаем ссылку на массив плейлиста
        const.offs = 0
        bot.send_message(message2.chat.id, "It's a search")

#Парсим команду вкплейлиста
@bot.message_handler(commands=["myvkplaylist"])
def handle_command(message):
    #Вводное сообщение с запросом айди
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, parse_mode='HTML',
                     text="I need your or other person's vk page ID, write it to me <b>(whitout 'id', just numbers)</b>")
    #Парсим ответ
    @bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
    def handle_text(message):
        #Получаем ссылку на массив плейлиста
        const.offs = 0
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "It's a playlist")
bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I find something, it's working with register_next_step_handler

```
import telebot
import const

#Подключаюсь к боту
bot = telebot.TeleBot(const.token)


#Поиск по запросу
#Парсим команду серч
@bot.message_handler(commands=["search", "start"])
def searching(search):
    answer = bot.send_message(search.from_user.id, "Give search request, name of song etc")
    bot.register_next_step_handler(answer, searchanswer)

def searchanswer(search):
    answer = search.text
    bot.send_message(search.from_user.id, answer + " It's search" )

@bot.message_handler(commands=["vkplaylist"])
def vkplaylist(vkid):
    answer = bot.send_message(vkid.from_user.id, "Give vk page id")
    bot.register_next_step_handler(answer, vkplaylistanswer)
def vkplaylistanswer(vkid):
    answer = vkid.text
    bot.send_message(vkid.from_user.id, answer + " It's  playlist")


bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```